# Question Closed and Voted to Migrate Didn't Migrate

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, closed-questions

I closed and voted to migrate [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4084/title-capitalization-doubt-if-or-if) to [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com) where it clearly fits as a grammar question.  The question was locked by Community and closed by me, but it did not migrate.  Is this a bug?  I verified that I did indeed vote to migrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug due to some recent changes we made around "what's migratable?" checks between sites that I inadvertently introduced specifically for moderators.  Previously, the check for "does the destination site had *any* of the tags on this question?" was bypassed for moderators but not normal users...that was no longer the case with the refactor.

Since a build last night, this is again the case and moderators again bypass this check.

Also, I went back and migrated that question, thanks for the report!